# Do we want a Community Facebook page?

Tags: discussion

https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/871/our-unofficial-facebook-page

Movies.stackoverflow has a facebook page which is used to share interesting questions, answers or meta posts through the use of a facebook page.

It is my understanding that this is beneficial to a site like movies because everyone watches movies, whereas not everyone is a developer for example. This aids them in gaining extra traffic through the ability to share and pass around posts to a large group of people.

I feel that the workplace is also something that could benefit from a community facebook page for a few reasons.

1.) Like movies, everyone has a job, and people are always facing work related problems.

2.) It could gain us lots of extra traffic, which would be nice to get, especially for increasing our questions per day.

3.) Facebook is a very large platform with access to a lot of people, if even 1% take interest in it that's still a huge amount.

Of course this is not without its disadvantages, namely:

-Someone would have to maintain posting interesting things to it

-Someone would have to moderate the comments on it as its a public facing view and racist / abuse comments would not help

I'm not entirely sure how people will react to this, or if it is even feasible for a beta site to do, but in either case I thought it would be an interesting proposal to put to you all to see what you think.

Comment: What about sharing links to interesting and relevant Workplace questions on your own Facebook feed?  My guess is you probably have more followers, followers who trust your opinion, better than a page.  From my experience, creating an online community to try to direct traffic to another online community -- Facebook to Stack Exchange -- doesn't always work as expected. There's a user on PMSE who tried this with a Linked-In group, and people were just asking questions in the group instead of visiting PMSE :)  Don't let me discourage you though if you do this. Every community/topic is different.

Comment: just the question you'll need to answer is how do you get people to post *here*, on The Workplace Stack Exchange, and not on the Facebook page. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Does Stack Exchange have any sort of policy on this sort of thing?

Comment: @enderland The only relevant policy (I know of) is for the use of the site's name, logo and design elements. The short version: don't use them and talk with SE to find suitable alternatives (see: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3966). However, no idea how that policy applies for beta sites.

Comment: @enderland, here's an example of what I consider to be a major failure :D  https://www.facebook.com/pages/Project-Management-QA/199284413419958?ref=hl  I'm no social media expert, so don't take my lack of success as an assertion that we can't succeed on social networks. The problem is that none of my Facebook friends see the page, but they *do* see direct questions I share with them on my own personal wall.

Comment: Another strategy that works really well is to look for existing conversations in the comments on your Facebook feed. If people are talking about a topic that relates to the Workplace, you could use that as an opportunity to jump in and participate and share a link to a relevant post. :)

Comment: i'm going to point out that if the purpose of the two 'answers' here is to determine peoples' interest in a community facebook page, there shouldn't be any downvoting.  Just because you feel one way or the other doesn't mean that you should remove the vote of someone else.

Comment: @acolyte But... but... but... when will I ever get the chance to downvote Jim on Meta???

Comment: I've only been counting the positive votes anyway, but the consensus is still a resounding no from the 14 members that participated...

Answer (score 11):

### No

Reasons:

- People are likely to ask and answer questions on facebook instead of coming here.
- Someone would need to take on the responsibility of maintaining it.
- Anonymity is much more difficult on Facebook and will limit the audience there.

Comment: While this at its heart is a yes-or-no question, I think it'd be useful if you explained some of the reasoning behind your no. Alternately/additionally, I'd recommend making this CW so it's easier for others to edit in their reasons for a "No" answer.

Comment: Your wish is granted.

Comment: If you want to stay anonymous, you're not going to post on FB. Is finding a monitor that difficult?

Comment: @JeffO - Our moderators are not on duty 24/7 and neither will any facebook group mods most likely

Comment: Facebook is already far too ingrained to our society.  There is something to be said for a proffessional site that deliberately keeps itself away from Facebook.  Might we lose some potential users?  Yes.  But there's a certain image I feel we should be trying to foster, and I don't think that being on Facebook would be beneficial towards that end.  Instead, perhaps some of the more major business blogs and/or news sites should be contacted, as they are far more likely to bring in the expert questions and answers we'd be looking for.

Comment: With Anonymity would this be solved by people messaging the page directly and then the page Admin posting it on their behalf?

Answer (score -1):

### Yes.

- Facebook is one of the highest-traffic sites on the internet. It would be a great place to get additional visibility for the site to attract new users.
- It would give us a place to have discussion about questions without cluttering up the SE site

Comment: I added the discussion part because I think it is actually the feature I think would best serve this SE.  The community seems to cry out for somewhere other than chat to have discussion, this could be the solution.\

Comment: If the goal is to drive traffic here, then external sites that point here (like a Facebook page) are all good - if and only if you don't permit the asking and answering of questions there.